# Problem with authorizing my requests to Spotify API via postman

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, postman, spotify

I'm building a Spring Boot service using Spotify Web API and wanted to test my controller methods. Using a browser, I could check the GET request and everything worked fine - I received the expected responses. The problem occurred when I wanted to check POST requests using Postman. Despite configuring authorization via OAuth 2.0 in Postman and receiving access tokens, every time I tried to make a request, the source code of the Spotify login page was returned, regardless of whether it was a POST or GET request.

This is how my spotify configuration in application.properties file looks like:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spotify.client-id=${SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spotify.client-secret=${SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spotify.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spotify.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/spotify
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spotify.scope=user-read-email,user-read-private
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spotify.authorization-uri=https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spotify.token-uri=https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spotify.provider=spotify
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spotify.user-info-uri=https://api.spotify.com/v1/me
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spotify.user-name-attribute=id
```

I have the same Redirect URI set in the app settings on the Spotify website.

The service where there is an example method that I wanted to test looks like this:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpotifyService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final String BASE_URL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/";

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public <T> T fetchData(String id, String endpoint, String accessToken, Class<T> responseType) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBearerAuth(accessToken);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                BASE_URL + endpoint + "/" + id,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                entity,
                String.class
        );

        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), responseType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ArtistDto getArtist(String artistId, String accessToken) {

        return fetchData(
                artistId,
                "artists",
                accessToken,
                ArtistDto.class
        );
    }
}
```

And the controller for that:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/spotify")
public class SpotifyController {

    private final SpotifyService spotifyService;
    private final TokenService tokenService;

    @GetMapping("/artists/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ArtistDto> getArtist(@PathVariable String id) {
        String accessToken = tokenService.getAccessToken();
        ArtistDto artistDto = spotifyService.getArtist(id, accessToken);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(artistDto);
    }
}
```

I also have this token service which provides me the access token:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TokenService {
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

    public String getAccessToken() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                oauthToken.getName()
        );

        return client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

Like I said, when I checked the operation of this method in the browser, it returns me the correct data in JSON format, but when I do it in Postman, I receive the source code of the Spotify login page.

This is how my OAuth 2.0 configuration looks like in Postman:
[Postman OAuth 2.0 config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oexHl.png)

I don't use scopes because I want to get to public data. I also tried changing Grant Type to Client Credentials, but the result is the same - the token is generated correctly and included in the headers, but the response is still the login page.

I also tried to create an endpoint that returns the current access token via the browser and paste this token into Postman using Bearer Token authorization, but still to no avail.

I really hope someone can help me solve this problem.